# Programmatically create Hyperlink Column in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to create a data grid which has various columns. One of the columns needs to be a hyperlink to a URL. For example I may have records of people in the grid and there name will link to a URL ging to the users file. 
Is this done in silverlight using a programmatically created hyperlink.

I did this in asp by doing a RowDataBind method, I need to do this in Silverlight:

```
protected void gvOrderData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Setup links
        string OrderLink = "'http://crm1:5555/sfa/salesorder/edit.aspx?id={";

        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open(" + OrderLink + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SalesOrderID").ToString() + "}','tester','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');");
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't create a DataTemplate in code... But you can create a DataTemplate in XAML as a resource, and assign it to a column in code:

```
((DataGridTemplateColumn)dg.Columns[0]).CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["dt"];
```

from: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/12912/41962.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do it in code?  It could be done in XAML using a DataGridTemplateColumn with an appropriate template e.g:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="View" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}">
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

..and define the template in the page resources

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
      <HyperlinkButton x:Name="ViewLink"
                Style="{StaticResource ViewButton}"
                Click="ViewLink_Click">
      </HyperlinkButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

You could add some logic to open a child window in the code behind, or following a purist MVVM path, add a command to handle the Hyperlink click event.